# What is this plant found in Arizona that grew to 4 feet tall in a few months?

Tags: identification, weeds

This plant started growing this spring in my back yard in Arizona.  It is now a few months later and the plant is about 4 feet tall.

Can someone tell me what this is?

[image]

Comment: It's a weed, or a wild flower, depending on your point of view; can't remember its name, but anything that grows that fast is usually a weed. If you planted wild flower seeds at some time, it may have been in the mix. Hopefully someone else will remember its name...

Comment: Do you remember any flower on this guy?  I think Bamboo is right that this was part of a 'wild flower' garden.  Couldn't find an Arizona weed to match.  My guess is Penstemon...but Aster just might...why did Diane's answer get 'deleted'?

Comment: Did not see Diane's answer.  As to wild flower i hope it looks like either you  mentioned.  No colors yet just the green leafy stalk.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a healthy [horseweed (*Erigeron canadensis*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erigeron_canadensis). A noxious, roundup resistant, drought resistant annual weed. They can produce over a million wind dispersed seeds per plant, and the seeds can persist in the soil for a long time.

[image]
[image]